# f:ajax listener does not redirect page whereas p:ajax works fine

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, primefaces

I have two drop-down menus in a form, on changing the value on the first menu the second menu is refreshed(AJAX) and then I can submit the form using a button which performs some action in a view scoped bean and on completion redirects to success page, am facing a problem which I can't figure out

that is, when I was using the `<f:ajax>` tag:

1. When I submit the form without changing the menus, the action is performed and I get redirected normally.
2. when I change the menus and click submit button the action is performed but the page is never redirected

when using the `<p:ajax>` tag it worked as expected, I've been searching for awhile now, I guess the problem is about requesting ajax but I can't figure the specific reason, this is a snippet from the page.

XHTML

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group arabic">
            <h:selectOneMenu id="governorates" required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="#{msgBean.getRequired()}"
                                        styleClass="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%"
                                        value="#{propertyBean.property.propertyDetails.governate}"
                                        converter="#{governateConverter}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="اختر المحافظة"
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.availableGovernates}"
                                            var="governateObj" itemValue="#{governateObj}"
                                            itemLabel="#{governateObj.name}"/>
                <p:ajax listener="#{propertyBean.setValidCities}"
                                            update="governorate_message cities" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message id="governorate_message" for="governorates"
                                        infoClass="help-block" errorClass="help-block error" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <div class="form-group arabic">
            <h:selectOneMenu id="cities" required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="#{msgBean.getRequired()}"
                                        styleClass="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%"
                                        value="#{propertyBean.property.propertyDetails.city}"
                                        converter="#{cityConverter}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="اختر المدينة"
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{propertyBean.validCities}"
                                            var="cityObj" itemValue="#{cityObj}"
                                            itemLabel="#{cityObj.name}"/>
                <p:ajax update="cities" />

            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message id="city_message" for="cities" infoClass="help-block"
                                        errorClass="help-block error" />
        </div>
    </div>
<h:commandButton id="update" value="تعديل"
                            onclick="if( validate('submitForm')==true){ updateProperty();} else{ return false;}"
                            action="#{propertyBean.update}"
                            class="btn btn-green btn-lg arabic"
                            rendered="#{propertyBean.isNew == false}">
                            <f:param name="propertyId" value="#{propertyBean.property.id}">
                            </f:param>
                        </h:commandButton>
```

Java class

```
public String update() {
        System.out.println("updating");
            return navBean.redirectToSuccess();
        }
```

using `<f:ajax>` tag

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group arabic">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="governorates" required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{msgBean.getRequired()}"
            styleClass="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%"
            value="#{propertyBean.property.propertyDetails.governate}"
            converter="#{governateConverter}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="اختر المحافظة"
                noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.availableGovernates}"
                var="governateObj" itemValue="#{governateObj}"
                itemLabel="#{governateObj.name}"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur"  listener="#{propertyBean.setValidCities}" render="governorate_message cities" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:message id="governorate_message" for="governorates"
            infoClass="help-block" errorClass="help-block error" />
    </div>
</div>
```

the browser network shows the following when using `f:ajax`

request:

```
POST /Newgar_revamp/pages/add.xhtml HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2207
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFE3725BjJXsA1xKf
Referer: http://localhost:8080/Newgar_revamp/pages/add.xhtml?propertyId=3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B81FF21F23988CC8C98D84DA14B36F54
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/Newgar_revamp/pages/status/success.xhtml
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 21:24:32 GMT
```

but the browser never redirects to the success page

Comment: You didn't provide the `<f:ajax>` version but a common mistake is using `<f:ajax update="..."/>` instead of `<f:ajax render="..."/>`.

Comment: @ForguesR, yes sorry for that, but the <f:ajax> tag was used in the correct syntax as you mentioned

Comment: Whats the difference between those 2 cases in the browser console and network traffic?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the non-working version.  Also,  make sure to check the javascript console for any error when you select a value from the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: no errors appears in console

Comment: four letters: mcve [mcve]. Especially this part: `navBean.redirectToSuccess();` Since a 302 is not what I'd expect in an ajax response. Maybe PF optimized something or you run into bugs that are maybe [alread fixed](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2648) (therefor always state version info)